# A recursive language minus a recursively enumerable language results in a recursive language?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I know that a recursively enumerable language minus a recursive language results in a recursively enumerable language, but I'm confused with the above question.

Aren't all recursive languages also recursively enumerable? Does this mean the answer to the question is that a recursive language minus a recursively enumerable language results in a recursively enumerable language, but more specifically, a recursive language?

Comment: You talk about "the answer to the question" but you don't pose a question: just the statement "A recursive language minus an R.E. language results in a recursive language." It's certainly true that _a_ recursive language (e.g., $\emptyset$) minus _an_ R.E. language (well, any language) is recursive. Is the statement supposed to be that _every_ recursive language minus _every_ R.E. language is recursive? Are you supposed to be proving it? Proving it or finding a counterexample?

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be an r.e. language which is not recursive (for example, $L$ can be the language of descriptions of Turing machines that halt on the empty input). Then $\Sigma^*$ is recursive but $\Sigma^* \setminus L$ is not recursive (exercise).

---

More generally, when faced with a question like this, try the following two approaches in parallel:

1. Try to prove the claim.
2. Try to refute the claim using a counterexample.

The two approaches can even feed each other.